# summation in mysql does not work properly and returns 0

Tags: mysql

I have a sql query as follow:

[image]

but the problem is that if the the second select staement with dataitem=3 returns null then the whole calculation becomes 0. For example for first select I have 100 and for second it returns null. Adding them should result 100 but it gives back 0!!!!!

can anyone say the reason and also what to do to get rid of that?
Here is also copiable code:

```
select( (
    SELECT sum(Sentiment) 
      FROM entity_epoch_data 
     WHERE EpochID IN 
              (SELECT ID 
                 FROM epoch 
                WHERE StartDateTime>='2013-11-1' 
                  AND EndDateTime<='2013-11-30') 
       AND EntityID =86 
       AND DataitemType=0
       )+
      (SELECT sum(Sentiment) 
         FROM entity_epoch_data 
        WHERE EpochID IN 
              (SELECT ID 
                 FROM epoch 
                WHERE StartDateTime>='2013-11-1' 
                  AND EndDateTime<='2013-11-30') 
          AND EntityID =86 
          AND DataitemType=3)
    )
```

Comment: You should change the image with the sql code (if you don't know how to format just put it here and someone will)

Comment: You don't need subselects. Put your conditions directly in your `sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to the SQLs that represent values the `IFNULL` command like `IFNULL((select sum()......), 0)` it should work fine.

But a little peace of advice. You should improve that query.
I beleave that this query you do the same thing.

```
    SELECT sum(entity_epoch_data.Sentiment) 
      FROM entity_epoch_data INNER JOIN epoch
            ON entity_epoch_data.EpochID = epoch.id
     WHERE epoch.StartDateTime>='2013-11-1' 
       and epoch.EndDateTime<='2013-11-30'
       AND entity_epoch_data.EntityID =86 
       and entity_epoch_data.DataitemType in (0,3)
```

You are summing the sums of the DataitemType 3 and 0 it just can be one query with a join

Comment: Yes, of course. Therefore you have to name the colum sum and get it with whatever framework you are using like `sum(entity_epoch_data.Sentiment) as someName` and on the code you did, just get this column name.

Answer (score 1):

Adding null is undefined and therefore returns null or 0. You can use a CASE expression to avoid that problem.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE null = sentiment THEN 0 ELSE sentiment END) FROM ....
```

If your DB does not support CASE inside the SUM() function create a VIEW that uses CASE to substitute the null values with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` statements instead of the statements you're using.

```
select sum(case when StartDateTime>='2013-11-1' and EndDateTime<='2013-11-30' and       DataitemType=0 then Sentiment else 0 end) as Sentiment_0, sum(case when StartDateTime>='2013-11-1' and EndDateTime<='2013-11-30' and DataitemType=3 then Sentiment else 0 end) as Sentiment3 from (tables_joined) where  EntityID =86
```